# Returning all records sharing email address but that have different address, firstname and lastname

Tags: sql, oracle

Got an oracle table with records some of which share email addresses but with different firstname, lastname or address. How can I get only records that share email address but whose firstname,lastname or address. What I have so far:

```
SELECT unique_id, firstname, lastname, email ,address
FROM customers
WHERE email in (SELECT email
                FROM customers
                GROUP BY email
                HAVING COUNT(email) > 1)
```

This returns a list of records sharings email but in some rows firstname,lastname and address are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for the distinct counts of firstname,lastname and address to see if any of them is > 1.

```
SELECT unique_id,firstname,lastname,email,address
FROM customers 
WHERE email in (SELECT email 
                FROM customers 
                GROUP BY email 
                HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FIRSTNAME) > 1
                OR COUNT(DISTINCT LASTNAME) > 1
                OR COUNT(DISTINCT ADDRESS) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that change did it!

Answer (score 0):

To do it in a single table scan, you can use an analytic function:

```
SELECT unique_id,
       firstname,
       lastname,
       email,
       address
FROM   (
  SELECT unique_id,
         firstname,
         lastname,
         email,
         address,
         COUNT( DISTINCT firstname ) OVER ( PARTITION BY email ) AS num_fn,
         COUNT( DISTINCT lastname  ) OVER ( PARTITION BY email ) AS num_ln,
         COUNT( DISTINCT address   ) OVER ( PARTITION BY email ) AS num_ad
  FROM customers
)
WHERE    num_fn > 1 OR num_ln > 1 OR num_ad > 1
```